# How to get a list of ONLY my available methods in IRB?

Tags: ruby

Say I load some code into `irb` like the following:

```
class MyClass
  def m 
    #... something
  end
  def a
    #... something
  end
end
```

How can I get a list of **only** my available methods? If I run `MyClass.new.methods` I get back **all** of the available `instance methods`.

I would like to just see: `:m, :a`

Additionally, what if my `methods` aren't wrapped in a `class`?

```
def x 
  #... something
end
def z
  #... something
end
```

How do I see what's available? Calling `self.methods` (running: `methods`) doesn't even list my methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as below using [`Module#instance_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods):

> Returns an array containing the names of the public and protected instance methods in the receiver. For a module, these are the public and protected methods; for a class, they are the instance (not singleton) methods. With no argument, or with an argument that is false, the instance methods in mod are returned, otherwise the methods in mod and mod’s superclasses are returned.

```
class MyClass
  def m 
    #... something
  end
  def a
    #... something
  end
end
MyClass.instance_methods(false)
# => [:m, :a]
```

If you defined methods on top level like below, they will become **private** instance methods of the **`Object`** class. So I would use then [`Module#private_instance_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-private_instance_methods)

> Returns a list of the private instance methods defined in mod. If the optional parameter is not false, the methods of any ancestors are included.

```
def x 
  #... something
end
def z
  #... something
end

Object.private_instance_methods(false)
# => [:x, :z]
```

Comment: Nice! How about without a `class`?

Comment: That's fantastic +1, I actually get back `[:default_src_encoding, :irb_binding, :x, :z]` using: `Object.private_instance_methods(false)` perhaps its because of my Windows box? Will retest on my Mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a little trick that I often use, especially if I am trying to work with an object from a library I did not write:

```
obj = MyClass.new
obj.methods.sort - 0.methods   # => [:a, :m]
```

The number `0` has a small set of methods that are mostly just standard Ruby stuff you don't want to see.  You could do `Object.new` instead of `0` and that would be better because you would be able to see methods like `succ`, but it would be more typing.

The advantage of this over `MyClass.instance_methods(false)` is that it shows methods included from superclasses, methods included from modules, and methods that were defined dynamically.
Also, you typically have an *object* that you are inspecting rather than a class.

Comment: Great explanation, Thanks a lot +1! `MyClass.new.methods - Object.new.methods` works great, but how about for direct access to private instance methods not scoped in a class? Do you have an alternative solution for @Arup's:  `Object.private_instance_methods(false)` ?

Comment: It's not a problem: `obj.class`